# Getting the last day of previous/last month in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm using the following code, where month is the current month(where am I):

```
 lastDayOfLastMonth = month === 0 ? new Date(year - 1, 11, 0).getDate() : new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
```

the idea, is if I'm on the first month of an year, the previous month is the last month of the previous year.

If I'm on January 2018, is reporting that December 2017 last day was 30, which is not true, it was 31, but I don't figure why.

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The day part of the `Date` constructor is not 0-indexed, but the actual day of the month.  In your first condition, `new Date(year - 1, 11, 0).getDate()`, you will first initialize your date to be December 0, 2017.  The date constructor then corrects this as November 30, 2017.

If you want the last day of the previous month, you can ignore the ternary operator and do the following, as the `Date` constructor will make the necessary conversions:

```
lastDayOfLastMonth = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 0).getDate();
```

Note that `currentMonth` is still 0-indexed (i.e. January is month 0 and December is month 11)

Answer (score 0):

below also give you result you want

```
var LastDay =  new Date(year-1, 12, 0);
//new Date(year - 1, 11, 0).getDate() this line seems issue in your code
```

---

this one returns december 31 2017 for me

```
 var month = 0;//this you will get when do dt.getMonth() in January month
 var year = 2018;           
 var LastDay = new Date(year, month, 0);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = LastDay;
```

---

try this out its working for me

```
 var dt = new Date();
 var month = dt.getMonth();
 var year = 2018;

 var LastDay = new Date(year, month, 0);

 console.log(LastDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth();
// first month
if(n == 0){
    console.log(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 31).getDate());
}
```

Comment: A brief explanation of what the code does would be a good improvement. Consider adding one for the OP and the community at large

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
lastDayOfLastMonth = month === 0 ? new Date(year - 1, 12, 0).getDate(): 
                                   new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
```